# How to get AWS account details from account ID programatically?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

I have an AWS account ID in hand - say 1111111111, which gets generated when I create an account. I use a **non-organisational account** and want to get the account details programatically , using the AWS API. Is there a way to do it ?

I need details like Email ID , Account ARN, Account Name and Joined Time.

Comment: Do you mean fetch the account details of the AWS accounts' root user?

Comment: It can be any user. But I will be having the master account access. Organizations is a concept but I want to know a way to do it if organizations is not used

Answer (score 1):

From AWS CLI you can use the below command to get the account details

`aws organizations describe-account --account-id 1111111111`

which returns all the details you mentioned above. For more details refer this link [AWS CLI describe-account](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/organizations/describe-account.html)

You can also use the api `organizations.<your region>.amazonaws.com` to get the account details. For more details about this api refer the following link [DescribeAccount AWS API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/organizations/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeAccount.html)

Comment: I want to get for an account that doesnt use Organizations. Is there a way to do it?